# upgrade blackberry database

Tags: database, sqlite, blackberry, upgrade

In my application, I have a database that gets written out to the sdcard. We have had to make a lot of big changes to the database, so when the user upgrades the application, is there a way to delete and reinstall the database, but only on upgrade?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way to do this is to have a chunk of code in the upgrade that checks for the old database and if it finds an old database, do the upgrade.

This lets you control what happens, and also how it happens.

Comment: Also, writing a version to the DB will help you identify if an upgrade is needed and the type of upgrade that is needed. Fortunately version 1.0 can be the versionless one :-)

Comment: @RayVahey - Yes, having some clear way to quickly determine the version the database is at is also critical. Thanks for pointing that out.